# Noda Time Instance value not deserializing correctly

Tags: json.net, ravendb, nodatime

I'm currently using RavenDB to store a object that uses Noda Time's Instant class to store dates.

RavenDb stores the value as

"ArrivalTime": {
    "Ticks": 13507658019037497
  },

but when query the object it is always null and starts at the beginning of unix epoch time.

I have tried using the JsonConvert attribute, but the reader always returns a null value for the Instant type. Also if I use more than one attribute, it only refers to the first.

Should I be using noda time with RavenDb or just stick to regular datetime?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using RavenDB 2.5**

If you are able to use RavenDB 2.5, then you can have full Noda Time support and use Noda Time types in your domain entities.  You will need the [Noda Time extensions for RavenDB](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-NodaTime).

**Using RavenDB 2.0**

You are probably better off *not* using Noda Time in your domain entities.  Instead, use the built-in types such as `DateTimeOffset`, `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`.

You can use Noda Time in your application logic, but not in the persistence layer.  The `Instant.ToDateTimeOffset()` and `Instant.FromDateTimeOffset()` methods in Noda Time are very useful, and RavenDB works pretty good with `DateTimeOffset` values.  It stores them in ISO8601 format, and properly converts to UTC time during indexing.  This means that you can query an index of `DateTimeOffset` values without regard to offset conversion.